# how to select multiple images in react native expo

Tags: react-native

how to select multiple images in react native expo

```
 import React from 'react';
    import ImagesExample from './ImagesExample.js'

    const App = () => {
       return (
          <ImagesExample />
       )
    }
    export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no official way to select multiple images in expo via ImagePicker but we can select via file system

[check this link](http://%20https://github.com/polycarpou/expo-camera-roll-select)